# glShaderSource causing segfault

Tags: c, opengl

I am trying to learn graphics programming and I have written a simple OpenGL program that draws a triangle and should shade it red, however when I call the function `glShaderSource` for the the fragment shader it causes a segfault.

I don't know why it causes a segfault because the [spec page](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glShaderSource.xml) doesn't say anything about the function causing a segfault, and anything about the shaders being loaded into memory wrong can't be it either, as the vertex shader is loaded in the same way and when I call `glGetShaderInfoLog` and print the log it says the vertex shader compile fine.

Anyways heres my code that Loads the shaders and links the shading program...

```
int LoadShader(char* Filename, GLchar* ShaderSource) //dont call this function by itself as it doesnt free its own memory
{
FILE* z;
z = fopen(Filename, "rb");

if(z == NULL) {printf("Error: file \"%s\" does not exist...\n", Filename); return -1;}

unsigned long len = 0;

//get file length
fseek(z, 0, SEEK_END);
len = ftell(z);
rewind(z);

if(len == 0) {printf("Error reading file \"%s\"\n", Filename); return -1;}


ShaderSource = (char*)malloc((sizeof(char)) * len + 1); //allocate enough bytes for the file
if(ShaderSource == NULL) {puts("Memory Error"); return -1;}

size_t result = fread(ShaderSource, 1, len, z);
if( result != len) 
{
    puts("Reading Error"); 
    free(ShaderSource);
    ShaderSource = NULL;
    return -1;
}

ShaderSource[len] = 0; //make it null terminated

puts(ShaderSource); //debbugging

fclose(z);

return 1;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
GLuint MakeProgram(char* VSpath, char* FSpath){

GLuint  VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
GLuint  FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

GLchar* VSsource; 
GLchar* FSsource;

if(!LoadShader(VSpath, VSsource))
    return -1;


if(!LoadShader(FSpath, FSsource))
    return -1;


GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
int InfoLogLength;

//compile shaders
const char* VS = VSsource; // glShaderSource needs a const char
glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VS, NULL); //we use NULL for length becuase the source is null-terminated
glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);
//check
glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
char* VSerr;
VSerr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * InfoLogLength);

glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VSerr[0]);
printf("%s\n", VSerr);

free(VSerr);
VSerr = NULL;


//fragment shader
const char* FS = FSsource;
glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FS, NULL);
glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);
//check
glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
char* FSerr;
FSerr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * InfoLogLength);

glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FSerr[0]);
printf("%s\n", FSerr);

free(FSerr);
FSerr = NULL;


//link program
GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
glLinkProgram(ProgramID);
//check program
glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
char* err;
err = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * InfoLogLength);

glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &err[0]);
printf("%s\n", err);

free(err);

//free the shaders
free(VSsource);
VSsource = NULL;

free(FSsource);
FSsource = NULL;

glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

return ProgramID;
}
```

Comment: "Why is my code segfaulting?" = "debug my code" - not good enough. You could at least isolate *where* the segfault is occuring, and that this *is* an OpenGL issue.

Comment: I did isolate it... I said the call to glShaderSource when attempting to compile the Fragment Shader cause the fault, also the title practically says that this is an issue with part of OpenGL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a closer look at your actual declarations of `VSsource` (uninitialized), `FSsource` (uninitialized) and the implementation of `LoadShader (...)`. Because this is C and you do not pass things by reference any changes made to the `ShaderSource` pointer inside the `LoadShader (...)` function as you originally wrote it will not propagate outside the function.

In short, you implemented `LoadShader (...)` incorrectly. You need to actually change the address stored in the pointer you pass it (since you are allocating this memory inside the function), but you cannot do that since you currently pass it a `GLchar*`.

As for why GL accepts an uninitialized pointer for your first call to `glShaderSource (...)` I cannot say. Perhaps you are just extremely lucky? Regardless, you can correct your issue by altering `LoadShader` to take a `GLchar**` instead. I will illustrate the necessary changes below:

```
/* Originally, you made a copy of an uninitialized pointer and then proceeded to
   re-assign this copy a value when you called malloc (...) - you actually need
   to pass a pointer to your pointer so you can update the address outside of
   this function!
*/
int LoadShader(char* Filename, GLchar** pShaderSource) //dont call this function by itself as it doesnt free its own memory
{
  [...]
  *pShaderSource = (GLchar *)malloc((sizeof(GLchar)) * len + 1); //allocate enough bytes for the file

  GLchar* ShaderSource = *pShaderSource;
  [...]
}

GLuint MakeProgram(char* VSpath, char* FSpath){
  [...]
  GLchar* VSsource; /* Uninitialized */
  GLchar* FSsource; /* Uninitialized */

  if(!LoadShader(VSpath, &VSsource)) /* Pass the address of your pointer */
    return -1;

  if(!LoadShader(FSpath, &FSsource)) /* Pass the address of your pointer */
    return -1;

  /*
   * Now, since you did not pass copies of your pointers, you actually have
   *   *VALID* initialized memory addresses !
   */
  [...]
}
```

Alternatively, you could simply modify your function to return the address of the string you allocated. Instead of returning **-1** on failure like you do now, you could return **NULL**. Your function interface would be as simple as this if you chose to go that route: `GLchar* LoadShader (char* Filename)`.